# Spring data rest sorting fields with underscores

Tags: java, json, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

We are using a very simple setup of `@RepositoryRestResource` on top of a `PagingAndSortingRepository` connected to a postgres database. Also we have configured `spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE` to return pretty json. It was all fine and dandy until we started sorting. As we have discovered - sorting requires us to provide the actual class field names (which we of course have in camel case):

`get("/thing?sort=dateCreated,desc")`

And when we try to do javascript friendly

`get("/thing?sort=date_created,desc")`

it fails miserably because jpa tries to split the parameter by the underscore.

Is there a simple way to have the path params the same format as we have them in the json that we are returning?

Comment: Did you try `__` (2 underscores)? (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983047/spring-data-jpa-entity-property-names-contain-underscores)

Comment: Yep and that did not work either. Seems that `__` is just for custom methods.

Comment: Tried to reproduce it but it works fine -> [code on github](https://github.com/jannis-baratheon/stackoverflow/tree/master/40746303-spring-data-rest-sorting-fields-with-underscores). What versions are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a bug for this - [DATAREST-883](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-883). It was fixed and released. But then, due to regressions ([DATAREST-909](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-909)) this has been dropped in the very next release. [I asked them on Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/pull/222#issuecomment-263511154) if they plan to have this again as this has bitten me in the past as well. We'll see what they have to say about this.

For now you can:

- leave it be
- go with the camel case property names
- work around this (e.g. go with [Alan Haye's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40852014/4494577)) - this seems fragile IMHO, but probably will do in a short term.

The status of the feature in the spring-boot versions I've tested with:

- [1.4.0](https://www.versioneye.com/java/org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest/1.4.0.RELEASE) (spring-data-rest 2.5.2): not yet implemented
- [1.4.1](https://www.versioneye.com/java/org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest/1.4.1.RELEASE) (spring-data-rest 2.5.3): works -> [code](https://github.com/jannis-baratheon/stackoverflow--spring-data-rest-sorting-by-json-field-name)
- [1.4.2](https://www.versioneye.com/java/org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest/1.4.2.RELEASE) (spring-data-rest 2.5.5): dropped

Comment: Wow, thanks for the investigation! We will wait until it is fixed :)

Comment: It looks like this is still an issue as of sdr 3.4.6 ...

Comment: Still open as per [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/issues/1638).

Answer (score 4):

It is unclear whether you can do this in some Spring Data Rest specific way however you should be able to handle it by means of a standard Servlet filter which would look something like the below:

```
public class SortParameterConversionFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    // as we are extending Spring's GenericFilterBean
    // you can then *possibly* inject the RepositoryRestConfiguration
    // and use  RepositoryRestConfiguration#getSortParamName
    // to avoid hard coding
    private static final String SORT_PARAM_KEY = "sort";

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        if (shouldApply(request)) {
            chain.doFilter(new CollectionResourceRequestWrapper(request), res);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param request
     * @return True if this filter should be applied for this request, otherwise
     *         false.
     */
    protected boolean shouldApply(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getServletPath().matches("some-pattern");
    }

    /**
     * HttpServletRequestWrapper implementation which allows us to wrap and
     * modify the incoming request.
     *
     */
    public class CollectionResourceRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

        public ResourceRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
            super(request);
        }

        @Override
        public String getParameter(final String name) {
            if (name.equals(SORT_PARAM_KEY)) {
                String [] parts = super.getParameter(SORT_PARAM_KEY).split(",");
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                int index = 0;

                for (String part : parts) {
                    // using some mechanism of you choosing
                    // convert from underscore to camelCase
                    // Using the Guava library for example
                    String convertedPart = CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE.to(
                         CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL, part);
                    ++index;
                    builder.append(convertedPart).append(index < parts.length ? "," : "");
                }

                return builder.toString();
            }

            return super.getParameter(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case, I need to use `getParameterValues` instead `getParameter`