# Spring Data REST: cannot sort by LocalDateTime field

Tags: java, spring-data-rest

I am trying to sort results of a get query by using a `PagingAndSortingRepository` extended interface, it all works fine until I try to sort by a field which is of type `LocalDateTime`.

I checked the logs, when I use this field, the query just ignores sorting and there is no order by clause whatsoever.

**You can find a demo on *[here on GitHub](https://github.com/khooz/spring-data-rest-date-sorting-demo)*.**

#### Code

Model:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "simple_users")
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
public class SimpleUser implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Columns
    protected Long id;
    protected String username;
    protected LocalDateTime createdAt;
    //...

    // Constructors
    public SimpleUser() { /** Default copy constructor */ }
    //...

    // Getters
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    @JsonProperty("id")
    public Long getId () { return this.id; }

    @Column(name = "username")
    @JsonProperty("username")
    public String getUsername () { return this.username; }

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    @JsonProperty("created_at")
    public LocalDateTime getCreatedAt () { return this.createdAt; }
    //...
}
```

Interface:

```java
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "simple-users", path = "simple-users")
public interface SimpleUserInterface
    extends PagingAndSortingRepository<SimpleUser, Long>
{}
```

URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/simple-users?page=0&size=10&sort=created_at,desc
```

#### Update 1:

I have changed the `JsonProperty` name of the field from `created_at` to `jjaa` (an arbitary name) and the problem was solved; however I changed it `jj_aa` (an arbitary name with an underscore in-between) and the problem has risen again. It seems that there is a problem with naming json properties with underscore and sorting.

I would very much appreciate if anyone can tell me why this happens and preferably how to solve that, because changing so many names to avoid underscores means a heavy refactoring on both back and front-end.

Comment: Wish I'd knew why it is downvoted so I could provide more detail if needed.

Comment: You use hephen "-" in `@RepositoryRestResource` but use understore "_" in URL. Highly suggest remove any custom configuration and try URL `http://localhost:8080/simpleUsers?page=0&size=10&sort=createdAt,desc`

Comment: @yejianfengblue Thanks! that is actually a typo and I have fixed it. Nevertheless, it refuses to order the results by the `created_at` field; I get the result, but in the default order. However, it orders by the `username` and `id` fields just fine.

Comment: Remove any unrelated configuration such as `@DynamicInsert`. Use the [H2 memory database](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database) and [add test data](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-rest/blob/master/rest/src/main/java/payroll/LoadDatabase.java) on application startup, then upload the project to Github.

Comment: Thanks @yejianfengblue. I have added a link to the github repo of a working demo.

Comment: The problem is not sort by LocalDateTime but sort by name with `_`. The easieast solution is don't use `_` in json name.  According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/40862101/10009424, Spring Data REST supports sorting by name with `_` in some old version but rollback due to conflict with other functions.

Comment: Commented on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/issues/1638 I think issue may have been around a while