# findById() gives No property Id found

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have three entities.
(I am using xxx as a place holder for this example)

I have set up all their `@Entities` with

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "xxx")
public class xxx {

@Id
@Column(name = "xxx_id")
int xxx_id;
```

However, I am able to do:

`findById(int ...)` for only ONE of the entities in their respective Repository. 
When I try to do that for the other two entities, I get this problem:

> "Invalid derived query! No property id found for type xxx!"

I am able to run it and get the proper results. But why am I getting this error for two entities but not the other?

I set up the entities and their repositories exactly the same way. 
The ONLY difference is that in the entity whose repository does not return any errors, I am joining that entity with another entity whose repository fails, but I used *"mappedBy"* in the `@JoinColumns` section.

Could that have something to do with why that one has no problems?

Comment: `findById` method needs to have a field named `id` in the entity class. However in your `xxx` class, you have `xxx_id`, not `id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***How findBy... works?***

```
Entity:
private int clientid;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
```

***Query:***

```
findBy<Name_as_per_entity>
findByClientid(int clientid);
findByFirstnameAndLastname(String firstname, String lastname)
```

### Solution

> Because we treat the underscore character as a reserved character, we
>   strongly advise following standard Java naming conventions (that is,
>   not using underscores in property names but using camel case instead).

[Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions)

The ***underscore _*** is a ***reserved character*** in Spring Data query derivation to potentially allow manual property path description.

Stick to the Java naming conventions of using  [camel-case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) for member variable names and everything will work as expected.

[Also Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983047/spring-data-jpa-repository-methods-dont-recognize-property-names-with-underscor)

Comment: I agree with this answer. Use CamelCase and write findByxxxId(int xxxId)

Comment: Thank you.

That link you provided was very helpful in determining how SQL breaks down the name.

I made my variables like:
"xxxId"     
the @Column like "xxx_id"

And the repository functions like "findByxxxId"