# Spring data query not working properly, because the field is having Or in the name. Field name is - approvedOrRejectedBy

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Spring data query not working properly, because the field is having `Or` in it.

The field is `String approvedOrRejectedBy`. So while writing the query it is confusing with the default Or.

The query I wrote is:

```
List<Object> findAllByTimeStampBetweenAndCameraSlugInAndApprovedOrRejectedBy(long startTime, long endTime, List<String> cameraSlugs, String id);
```

Because of `Or` present in the field name, it's throwing an error. Any suggestions or workaround on how to solve this issue, other than updating the filed name and DB mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *query by method-name* will interpret certain keywords from the name:

- [Subject Keywords](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#appendix.query.method.subject) like here `findAllBy`
- [Predicate Keywords](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#appendix.query.method.predicate) like here `And`, `Or`, `Between` together with the property names

Since your field/property seems named as `approvedOrRejectedBy` you could work around by naming the object property differently and annotate it with the mapped DB-column name as given, e.g. `@Column(name "ApprovedOrRejectedBy")`.

```java
@Column(name "approvedOrRejectedBy")
String reviewedBy;
```

Then your query-method can be rewritten as

```java
List<Object> findAllByTimeStampBetweenAndCameraSlugInAndReviewedBy(long startTime, long endTime, List<String> cameraSlugs, String id);
```

Alternatively, since the method name becomes hard to read, you could shorten the name and specify the SELECT on `@Query` annotation like this:

```java
@Query("SELECT * FROM entityOrTable x WHERE x.timeStamp BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2 AND x.cameraSlug IN ?3 AND x.approvedOrRejectedBy = ?4")
List<Object> findByIntervalCameraSlugInAndReviewedBy(long startTime, long endTime, List<String> cameraSlugs, String id);
```

See also:

- [Spring-Data-Jpa Repository - Underscore on Entity Column Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23456197/spring-data-jpa-repository-underscore-on-entity-column-name)
- [Spring Data JPA repository methods don't recognize property names with underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983047/spring-data-jpa-repository-methods-dont-recognize-property-names-with-underscor)

Comment: Woo...! Thanks a lot. It worked. :)

Comment: Get practical advice on JPA query by method-names: [Spring Data JPA Tutorial: Creating Database Queries From Method Names](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-creating-database-queries-from-method-names/)

Answer (score 0):

Try writing custom query using JPQL, like @Query annotation. Please see

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query